# Controlling relative size of points in ggplot2 plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to draw many different tile plots, which have squares and dots on top of the tiles according to 
data. Unfortunately I cannot include illustrating picture, but basically the plot consist of tiles which either have squares and dots on them or not.

Each of those figures has different number of tiles on x-direction and y-direction. As a result, I cannot use  absolute units (mm) to scale the dot sizes and box sizes. Is there any way to specify the size of the dot in relative terms. For instance, like `geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), size = 0.5 * tile_size())`.

The following **buggy** code snippet

> `df <- data.frame(x=factor(c(1:4), labels=c("a", "b", "c", "d")), y=factor(c(1:4), labels=c("f", "g", "h", "j")))`
>   `p <- ggplot(data = df) + geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y), fill="green", color="black")`
>   `p <- p + opts(aspect.ratio=2)`
>  
>   `p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), color="red", size = 4, shape=15, color="red")`
>   `p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), color="blue", size = 2)`
>   `p <- p + scale_x_discrete("Variables") + scale_y_discrete("Time")`
>   `show(p)`

almost achieves the desired functionality, except if I resize the graphical window or the pdf dimensions, the relative size of  points and boxes with respect to the tile sizes changes. In particular, the dots and boxes might be larger than the tile they are drawn on, which is absolute no-no.

If relative scaling of point size is impossible, then I would like to know is it possible to specify the dimensions of the plot area (plot without axes labels, ticks and so on) using `ggsave()` or `pdf()`. Then I could do relative scaling by myself.

Comment: 'Sven: That `geom_point` code should work.  What's the problem?

Comment: If it's not working, give us some toy code to play with and state what you get and what you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to specify sizes in data units, rather than physical units.  This is something that is a little tricky for circles and squares because they may actually be ovals and rectangles in data space (unless you are using `coord_equal`).  But if you want to do this, you can generate the glyphs yourself and use `geom_polygon` to draw them.