# R - gridExtra - some layer of ggplot() does not scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have a bunch of `ggplot()`s with two layers: a `geom_boxplot` and and a `geom_points`.

When I insert these in a grid using `gridExtra`, the `geom_boxplot` scales but the `geom_point` does not, which results in something ugly (see e.g., picture below).

How can I address this issue please?

**Reproducible Code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
datablock <- data.frame(date = rep(1:10, 3)
              , value = rnorm(30, 3,2)
              , name = c(rep("one",10), rep("two",10), rep("three",10)))
currentValues <- data.frame(date = rep(1,3)
              , value = c(3, 2.3, 3.5)
              , name = c("one","two", "three"))
boxplotFg <-   
  ggplot(datablock, aes(x = name, y = value)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
  geom_point(data=currentValues, aes(x=name, y=value, color = value), size = 8)


 grid.arrange(boxplotFg,boxplotFg, boxplotFg, boxplotFg,boxplotFg, boxplotFg, ncol = 3)
```

**Output:**

[image]

I could of course decrease the size of the `geom_point`s to, say, 4 or 5... but I feel like varying the absolute size is not the right way since it will only solve the issue generally.

Comment: Controlling relative size of points in ggplot2 plots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870303/controlling-relative-size-of-points-in-ggplot2-plots

Comment: @MarcoSandri it will be extremely challenging to control the aspect ratio of the points using that method. Particularly as the relative scaling in the x and y directions will need to change depending on the size of the graphics output, so can't easily be determined algorithmically.

Comment: grid viewports are meant to offer some inheritance properties to scale grob sizes relative to the parent context, but AFAIK it's never really been used/implemented in a systematic way. As an example, consider `print(qplot(1,1)+theme_bw(2), vp=viewport(gp=gpar(cex=10)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is to scale the point size according to the number of grid columns.

```
nc = 3
boxplotFg <-   
  ggplot(datablock, aes(x = name, y = value)) 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
    geom_point(data=currentValues, aes(x=name, y=value, color = value), 
      size = 8/nc)
grid.arrange(boxplotFg, boxplotFg, boxplotFg, boxplotFg,boxplotFg, boxplotFg, 
  ncol = nc)
```

[image]

The same code but with `nc=2` yields

[image]